# Manipulate - 3 sliders for a list of 3 elements

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate, graphics3d, slider

I'm trying to create a slider for a list of 3 elements. I know that I can create a 2D slider for a list of 2 elements and it's impossible to create a 3D slider for a list of 3 elements. So, I just want to know if it's possible to create 3 sliders for a list of 3 elements in the same horizontal line, instead of 1 slider for each individual element like the costum way.

I want to create a program that exemplifies the 3 body problem in 3 dimensions. So, I have 9 generalized coordinates: x1,x2,x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3 (i=1,2,3 it's the number of the body).
Wich corresponds to the list:

> X={{x1,x2,x3},{y1,y2,y3},{z1,z2,z3}}

A 3D graphic will need 3 sliders for each body. How could I make 3 sliders for each list, {x1,x2,x3},{y1,y2,y3} and {z1,z2,z3}?

I tried to create 1 slider for each individual element ,and it just said:

> "Array {0.3, 0.4, 0.5} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list"

even when using a $ParametricPlot3D$.

Comment: somehing like `Column[{Row[Slider /@ {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y, Dynamic@z}, Spacer[5]], 
  Dynamic@{x, y, z}}]`?